# How to highlight active slider with Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have two sliders on my page, with range between 0 and 100. The user is supposed to choose the value of the slider by clicking on it, and then potentially using the arrow keys of the keyboard (for precision).

How can I highlight (= change the appearance) of the active slider, so that it is obvious for the user which value (s)he is choosing?

Comment: Maybe use pseudo class `:focus` in CSS?

Comment: @Syscall thank you! Would people mind explaining the downvotes? Is it because the question is too obvious? Sorry if it is the case.

Comment: Your question lacks research effort.  You don't say what you have tried or include any markup/code to show your issue.  I would have expected that you would have googled "html active" which would probably lead you down the path of pseudo selectors.  You don't mention that you tried pseudo selectors and that they didn't work, or discuss using click events or any other attempts at a solution.

Comment: @zero298 thank you very much for taking the time to explain. I googled "highlight active slider", "highlight active element" and other related expressions and couldn't find anything. I just didn't know how to formulate it properly, and I am far away from even knowing what pseudo-selectors are. Sometimes it is not easy to know where to look. But I'll try to ask better questions in the future. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `:focus` CSS pseudo selector.  Properties that will be visibly indicated differ between browsers.  For example, Chrome won't show `background-color` or `border`, but **will** show `outline`.

```css
input[type="range"]:focus {
  background-color: blue;
  border: 2px solid red;
  outline: 2px solid red;
}
```

```html
<input type="range" min="0" max="100" step="5">
<input type="range" min="0" max="100" step="5">
```

Comment: @AlonEitan Updated answer with a solution that will work with Chrome.

Comment: Thank you very much. Just one detail, it is the opposite, right? (Chrome shows background-color and border but not outline.)

Comment: @Oliv I'm using Chrome 64.0.3282.186 and I do not see `background-color` working.

Comment: @zero298 I am using Chrome 60.0.3112.113 and background-color is working here (but not outline).